# Rational dynamical system with nonnegative paramaters and with nonnegative initial conditions

Tags: dynamical-systems, parametric, chaos-theory

let $A$ be a rational system of the form :\begin{cases} x_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_{1}}{y_{n}} \\  y_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_{2}}{z_{n}} \\ z_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_{3+}+\beta_{3}x_{n}+\sigma_{3}y_{n}+\lambda_{3}z_{n}}{A_{3}+B_{3}x_{n}+c_{3}y_{n}+D_{3}z_{n}}{}\end{cases}
$n=0,1,....$

with nonnegative paramaters and with nonnegative initial conditions such that the denominators are always positive.

how i could show that :for every positive solution of the difference equation:
$z_{n+1}= \frac{\alpha}{1+\prod_{i=0}^{k}z_{n-i}},n=0,1,.... $ has a finit limit ?

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188653/rational-dynamical-system-with-nonnegative-paramaters